# Turbocharger Electronic Valve Control

Tags: solenoid, hardware, actuator

I have seen that the H bridge method is used to drive the valves required to use the turbocharger feature in the engines, why do they prefer this? There is no DC motor, they open and close an electromechanical pressure control valve at a certain rate? What could be the reason for doing this with the H-Bridge IC?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a motor, have one on my car controlling the variable vanes that modulates the output of the turbo.

The control you refer to is the wastegate - a simple pressure limiting control of max pressure.

The variable turbos limit to the  max pressure by reducing the effectiveness of the turbine based on the velocity triangle between the varaible and rotating blades.

Comment: It says it's a solenoid valve, not a motor, but it's controlled by H-Bridge, I couldn't figure out this link. How is H-Bridge used in electromechanical valve control other than motor driving?